# Prioritizing original terms over synonyms in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-analyzers

In my analyzer pipeline I have a synonyms function.

Let's say that I have the following synonyms

```
beverage, drink
```

Now let's say that a user searches for 'beverage', the user will get documents that contain 'beverage' or 'drink' without any preference.

The thing is that I want to give a **higher score** to documents that contain the **original search term** ('beverage' in this case) and a **lower score** to its **synonyms** ('drink' in this case).

What's the best and cheapest way for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another subfield in the mapping without the synonyms.

In the query you match on both fields.

**Index**

```
PUT synonym_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "beverage, drink"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "search_analyzer": "synonym",
        "fields": {
          "no_synonyms": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Documents**

```
POST synonym_index/_doc/1
{
  "name": "beverage"
}

POST synonym_index/_doc/2
{
  "name": "drink"
}
```

**Query**

```
GET synonym_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "beverage",
      "type": "most_fields",
      "fields": [
        "name",
        "name.no_synonyms"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will this query score give a higher score to the original term over the synonyms? Or should I boost it?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work if in the request query will be a priority for the field "name.no_synonyms"
So, you need to use a [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.4/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#:%7E:text=caret%20(%5E)-,notation,-%3A) query in your request and search for the two fields "name" and second "name.no_synonyms" with higher priority for "name.no_synonym"

Example of the query

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "drink",
      "fields": [
        "name.no_synonyms^10",
        "name"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```